# Django -- Python -- How to have a global templatetags shared among all my apps in one project

Tags: django, django-templates, tags

Let say that I have:

```
proj1/app1
proj1/app1/templatetags/my_shared_tags.py
proj1/app2
proj1/templates
proj1/templates/app1/index.html
proj1/templates/app2/index.html
```

Now, how can I reuse a tag from `my_shared_tag.py` from app1 in my app2.

Comment: Jim's answer is correct, there's nothing preventing you from using all your templatetags.  Maybe you are forgetting {% load ... %} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried doing it?

I'm pretty sure you can use all template tags in all templates out of the box with django :)

Comment: I did try that. Error saying that it couldn't find the tags.
I used:

{% load my_shared_tags %}
{% load app1/my_shared_tags %}
{% load app1/templatetags/my_shared_tags %}

No luck. 

I am wondering if I can put the project wide template tags
right under the proj1/templatetags/my_shared_tags.py
and have all the apps use it.

If you have the exact syntax, it would be great.

Comment: A couple more things to check: Is the app that contains the template tags installed? does the templatetags dir contain an "__init__.py" file?